# new Yodlee API or RESTful Wrapper API , Confusions galore for someone starting on Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to implement account aggregation solution and am confused right now as there are multiple API's available that do the same thing.

I came across new Yodlee API as well as RESTful Wrapper APIs'. Both of these API classifications do the same thing but provide different APIs sets.

Can someone please let me know which one should I use?

I am referring to this link
https://developer.yodlee.com/API_Resources/API_Reference

Answer (score 0):

Please go with Yodlee APIs, which is our latest product.

This is purely REST and the API response is simple, informative and decluttered. Here Webhooks is also supported

Please refer- https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API

API Flow- https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/API_Flow/Add_Account_With_ProviderAccount

Swagger tool( to test APIs)- https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/providerAccounts

Hope this helps you in getting started.

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: That's what I thought too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your documentation(API Reference) mentions some fields/endpoints deprecated but they still work in the old style. I find document inconsistent.

Also i could not even find a support email where i could even mail about this problem.

I would appreciate if you consider these points.

Thanks